# NotWritablePropertyException: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring, beancreationexception

I am implementing Spring Transaction in my application service layer..

I was referring to example on tutorials point for programmatic way of implementing spring transaction...

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/programmatic_management.htm

I followed each & every step mentioned over there....but getting issue with bean creation in the xml file..

Error:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [database/spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

system & application configuration: 
OS: ubuntu 16.0.4 
spring version: - 5.0.3 
tomcat: 9
jdk: 1.9
IDE: Eclipse Oxygen 3

It will be very helpful for me if any one can give me the solution...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

       <!-- ********************* Initialization for Inventory database -->

         <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="root" />
        </bean>

        <!--*********************  Initialization for TransactionManager -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
          <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>    
       </bean> 

    </beans>


public class MyService implements InventoryServiceIface{

    private MyDAO dao;

    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public void setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {

        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    public void setDAO(MyDAO dao) {

        this.dao = dao;
    }


    public Student saveStudent(Student tudent) throws ServiceException{

              validate(Student); // validate the data inside party object 

              TransactionStatus status = beginTransaction(); // begin database transaction

              try 
              {
                  rollbackTransaction();
                  Student =  dao.saveStudent(student); 
              }
              catch(ServiceException e)
              {
                   rollbackTransaction(status);
                   throw e;
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                   rollbackTransaction(status);
                   throw new ServiceException(e);
              }

               commitTransaction(status);

          return student;
    }

    public TransactionStatus beginTransaction()

    {
        System.out.println("TRANSACTION BEGINS....");
        return transactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());

    }

    public void rollbackTransaction(TransactionStatus status)

    {
        System.out.println("ROLL BACK....");
        transactionManager.rollback(status);

    }

    public void commitTransaction(TransactionStatus status)

    {
        System.out.println("TRANSACTION COMMITTED....");
        transactionManager.commit(status);

    }

}// End of Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property name of DataSourceTransactionManager that set the datasource is as writen in the stacktrace dataSource and not xxxxxDataSource . you config should be as follow

```
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.
        DataSourceTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="xxxxDataSource"> 
         </property>    
       </bean>
```

Comment: OK...got It....Thanks a lot biiyamn... I took more time to understand...thank you once again...